# What are the root causes of inflation, other than cost-pull/push inflation?

Tags: macroeconomics, inflation

What I have found so far:

1. Apparently, increases in regulatory costs lead to reduced competition an therefore to inflation. However, in normal economic circumstances, as long as competition exists, how can there be inflation?
2. Desinflation may lead to a liquidity trap. However, hypothetically speaking, if the government made it clear that prices are expected to fall only during X period of time, would this be a solution to the liquidity trap?